# Determine whether two or more objects in a list are equal according to some property

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

Say I have a list `List<MyObject> myObjectList`. The `MyObject` object has a property named `Order` which is of type `int`. How can I determine whether two or more objects in `myObjectList` have the same `Order` using LINQ-to-objects?

Answer (score 11):

First [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) `MyObject.Order` and then determine if [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) of the groups have more than one member:

```
bool b = myObjectList.GroupBy(x => x.Order)
                     .Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
// b is true is there are at least two objects with the same Order
// b is false otherwise
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bool hasDuplicates = myObjectList.Count >
    new HashSet<int>(myObjectList.Select(x => x.Order)).Count;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a pure Linq-To-Objects-Solution, but how about:

```
var ordersList = new List<Order>(myObjectList.Select(obj => obj.Order);
bool allUnique = ordersList.Count == new HashSet<Order>(ordersList).Count;
```

One would have to test performance of all the approaches presented here. I'd be careful, otherwise you end up quickly with some slow O(n²) look-ups.

Comment: You could improve performance by avoiding the intermediate `List<Order>`. The `HashSet<T>` constructor can take an `IEnumerable<T>` directly.

Comment: @Luke, yap thanks, I overcomplicating. Of course the ordersList will always have the same count as the original list.

Comment: @Jason, I think I originally saw some answers posted with some Count() statements nested. And Count() in Linq is definately evil.

Answer (score 1):

What about `Distinct`?

```
bool allUnique = ordersList.Count == ordersList.Select(o => o.Order).Distinct().Count()
```

Answer (score -1):

The `Count()` method takes a predicate, so you would do something like this:

```
if(myObjectList.Count(x => x.Order == 1) >= 2)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: That only checks if there is a duplicate with `MyObject.Order` equal to `1`. It ignores the possibility of there being a duplicate with `MyObject.Order` equal to any other `int`.

Comment: This would only test whether there are multiple objects with Order==1, not if there are two objects with the same (unknown) value.